# connect-redis redisClient.connect() connecting to wrong IP

Tags: node.js, express, node-redis

I am getting the following error message.

```
app    | Redis error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
app    |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16) {
app    |   errno: -111,
app    |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
app    |   syscall: 'connect',
app    |   address: '127.0.0.1',
app    |   port: 6379
app    | }
```

It is connecting to 127.0.0.1, even though I have hard-coded the ip address as 172.19.0.3. I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but the app, and redis db are both in docker containers. I have supplied the external IP for the redis container.

```js
// Session / Redis
const session = require('express-session');
const redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
// redis@v4
const { createClient } = require("redis")
const redisClient = createClient({
  legacyMode: true,
  host: '172.19.0.3'
});
redisClient.connect()
    .catch(console.error)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connected to Redis server successfully');
    });

app.use(
    session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    name: '_redisSessionId',
    resave: false,
    saveUnitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        path: '/',
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false,
        maxAge: 60000 // 30 minutes
    },
  store: new redisStore({
    host: '172.19.0.3', //process.env.REDIS_HOST,
    port: 6379,
    client: redisClient,
    ttl: 86400
  })
}))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/9ffae592f1023cc1e675eb7ec25a21f4f03de66e/docs/client-configuration.md) your `createClient` options should look like:

```js
{
  url: 'redis://172.19.0.3',
  legacyMode: true,
}
```

and [creating the connect-redis store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-redis) should look like:

```js
new redisStore({ client: redisClient });
```

Comment: thank you so much. I had just updated from redis v3 to v4. I knew I was doing something stupid.